# Copy location keyframe of an object to a specific bone

Tags: animation, armature, bones

Basically the title, I have a cube that has several location key frames, and I need it on an unconnected bone that is part of a bigger armature. I tried using the action editor to do this by applying the cube animation onto the armature, but that just applies the animation to the entire armature, I don't know how I can specify a specific bone.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just after I posted this I figured it out. Turns out you can just Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V all of the keyframes, the trick is to set a single keyframe first on the object/bone you want to paste the animation into, and then Ctrl-V inside the F-Curve editor.

Comment: Can you help me ? If I do this my bone position will be animating to the wring position after keyframe paste.